# Beam excited RF cavity modes

Tags: accelerator-physics

When beam (bunch of electrons) transverse RF cavity, it will excite modes (resonant frequencies). The mode for steady state is quite well described, I am wondering is there any theory describe the field evolution inside the cavity when the beam moves inside the cavity.
This is a question more relevant to accelerator physics.

Comment: I can tell you that people design cavities to have specific modes excited for building beam position and current monitors (which use different modes). I think you can assume that this means they know how that works. But *I* don't.

Comment: Much of this work is done numerically, with high frequency E&M simulation software.

Comment: Hi guys, I am more interested in the transient part.Definitely it is a normal practice to use EM simulation. But The underlying process needs to be clarified somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that one can calculate the fields due to a moving charge (along with its image charges) and then calculate overlap integrals with higher-order mode (HOM) fields. Perhaps this procedure can give, analytically, the amplitudes for exciting HOMs. In practice I think this is encapsulated as a separate cavity resistance for each mode.

Comment: resorting to Maxwell equations is always a correct way. But it seems quite hard to fit into the mode concepts in the transient part. Definitely, each mode has different impedance.